# No guarda el Job cuando se hace un dispatch - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

Estoy tratando de crear un Job utilizando `Queues`, es muy simple lo que quiero hacer.
Cuando se ingresa a una ruta, `api/products`, se ejecuta el metodo `ìndex` del controller, en cual se realiza un `dispatch` de un `Job`:

```
public function index()
{
    dispatch(new ProcesHistoryJob());
    return new ProductCollection(Product::all());
}
```

`ProcesHistoryJob()` Solamente inserta un valor `faker` en una tabla

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

use App\ProcesHistory;

class ProcesHistoryJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    public function handle()
    {
        factory(ProcesHistory::class)->create();
    }
}
```

Todo el codigo funciona correctamente, solo que nunca veo que se inserte en la tabla `jobs`.
Obviamente si no pasa por la tabla muchos menos lo va a 'escuchar'. `php artisan queue:liste`

cuando se llama `dispatch()` no tendria que inserta un registro en la tabla `jobs`, una tarea 'encolada', para que luego `queue:liste` la ejecute?

Answer (score 0):

Ya logre resolverlo.

hay que configuracion la siguente varibale de entorno en el `.env`

`QUEUE_CONNECTION=database`

De esta manera cada vez que se hace un dispatch de una job se almacena en la tabla `jobs` para luego ser ejecutada en segundo plano.